# Find if a range exists in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

How can I list the names of the worksheets in a Google SpreadSheet? I am trying to find if a worksheet exists using DataFilters

This is my function

```
public bool RangeExists(string sheet, string range)
        {
            BatchGetValuesByDataFilterRequest r = new BatchGetValuesByDataFilterRequest();
            DataFilter filter = new DataFilter();
            filter.A1Range = range;
            r.DataFilters = new List<DataFilter>() { filter };
            var a = service.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchGetByDataFilter(r, sheet).Execute();
            return a.ValueRange.Count>0;
        }
```

This code throws this exception when I try to find if my spreadsheet has a sheet called "Sheet":

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid dataFilter[0]: Unable to parse range: Sheet!A:ZZ [400]
Errors [
    Message[Invalid dataFilter[0]: Unable to parse range: Sheet!A:ZZ] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [REST Resource: spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets) you'll notice that there's a sheets property that should display all the sheets within a spreadsheet.

```
"sheets": [
    {
      object(Sheet)
    }
  ]
```

So, what you can do is to make a call to [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). This will return that sheets object which you're looking for. You can use the Try-it from that link and indicate '*' in the "fields" parameter to return all properties (that includes the sheets).